# How to force a line break from string content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm loading data for a page dynamically depending on the data I get from my backend , My code looks like this :

```
 return (
    <p className="font-mukta tracking-0.165 text-center lg:text-start text-32px md:text-44px xl:text-6xl font-medium pb-2 md:pb-0 xl:leading-snug">
          {title}
        </p>
```

if my title for example is: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and I want to add a line break after a certain word in that text , for example a line break after the word simply but it's dynamic ,Is there anyway I can force a  line break from the string itself for example by adding the html tag `<br>` or `/n` in the actual string but that doesn't really work , Any tips ?

Comment: Do you want to add a true line break, or could you achieve the results with some CSS?

Comment: I want the line break to be included within the string sent from backend , for example If i add a /n to add a new line , basically to leave the option of a new line within the backend , is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the replace method on the text variable to add a break tag after every occurrence of the particular word.

```
return (
    <p className="font-mukta tracking-0.165 text-center lg:text-start text-32px md:text-44px xl:text-6xl font-medium pb-2 md:pb-0 xl:leading-snug">
          {title.replace("word", "word <br>")}
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are going to set the title with some html tags then it will escape all those and simply write "" as a string. To just use the html syntax in the text of

   tag use the dangerouslySetInnerHtml

```js
   const createMarkup = ()=>{
          // add here the logic to replace that word with line break tags 
          const newtitle = title.replace('word','word <br>')
          
          return {__html: newtitle}
}
     return (
        <p className="font-mukta tracking-0.165 text-center lg:text-start text-32px 
     md:text-44px xl:text-6xl font-medium pb-2 md:pb-0 xl:leading-snug" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createTitle()} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it-

```
import React from "react";
const Test = ({ title }) => {
  //lets say we have to add a line break after the word simply
  const index = title.indexOf("simply");
  title =
    title.slice(0, index) +
    `simply<br>` +
    title.slice(index + "simply".length + 1);
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }}></div>;
};

export default Test;
```

We can find the index of the string that we want to add a break after and then do the calculation as shown above which will help in manipulating the string. Now we can set it using the prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as shown above.